# refactor a php 5 application with no framework to work with zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a complete web aplication with php5 my question is there an easy way to transform it so it work with zend framework?

```
<?php class Projet extends Modele
    {
        var $id_proj;
        var $libelle;
        var $date_Create;
        var $projet_html;
        var $html;
        var $nbr_bloc;
        var $date_modif;
        var $etat;
        var $width;
        var $height;
        var $bg_color;
        var $border;
        }
```

Comment: "I have a complete cabin that is made from pine, is there an easy way to replace it so it's made from oak?"

Comment: you can't trasfor anythong. :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no such **easy** way.

Comment: @gaRex i must recreate my application from the start?

Comment: As you will anyway invent some trasnfer way. And also some things in your app could be incompatible with zend's.

Comment: @strawberry, no. I mean you don't have *easy* way.

Comment: is there any tutorial you can suggest me?

Comment: @strawberry, I don't know such... May be some standard zend's manual or howto will help? Also you can try to find some already zend-based open source app and learn it from inside. Then you'll understand how to convert your app.

Comment: Go through the quickstart it will give you the basics of the default usage of the framework with a simple scenario. From there its a matter of learning ZF and then translating the existing code to work as a ZF application- but only you can answer what that conversion is going to look like because you wrote the app (or have access to the code) youre converting. Youll probably be able to keep some things and youll probably have to rewrite a lot of things.